# what does git merge origin/master do?

Tags: git, git-merge

After fetching from remote using `git fetch`, we need to use something like

```
git merge origin/master
```

I would like to know if this command also does `git commit` at the same time? Is the order `origin/master` important? Can I write `master/original`?

Comment: You really ought to work yourself through [The Book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches).

Answer (score 28):

`git merge origin/master` can do one of two things (or error).

In the first case, it creates a new commit that has two parents: the current `HEAD`, and the commit pointed to by the ref `origin/master` (unless you're doing something funny, this is likely to be (the local pointer to) the branch named `master` on a remote named `origin`, though this is completely conventional).

In the second case, where there is no tree-level merge necessary, rather than creating a new commit, it updates the currently checked-out ref to point to the same commit as is pointed to by `origin/master`. (This is called a *fast-forward* merge -- git can be directed to either always or never do this when you merge through command-line flags).

It does not call `git commit` directly, which is a higher-level (*porcelain* in the git-parlance) command intended for users.

Calling `git merge master/original` will try and resolve `master/original` to a commit, which will almost certainly (again, unless you've done something deliberate) **not** be the same as `origin/master`. If you happen to have a remote named `master` that has a branch named `original`, it will create a new commit which has that as the second parent.

You may find `git help rev-parse` to be helpful in deciphering how git attempts to resolve ref names or other notations into commits.

Answer (score 12):

What this does is merges the branch referred to as origin/master into your current branch. The order is **very** important. The word *origin* means the place from which you cloned your repository, i.e., the origin of the repository, the word *master* is just a branch name, however master is usually used as the main branch, or the *trunk* branch as some other systems call it.

Merge might need to do a commit depending on the state of your development. If your history hasn't diverged from the origin, it can do what is called a *fast-forward*---all that needs to be done is put the new history on top of yours. If your development has diverged from the origin then if the merge can be done with no conflicts then the merge is done and a new commit is recorded at HEAD to specify the merge and the two parents.

Furthermore, if merging can't be done because of a conflict, your working copy is updated to reflect the fact that there are conflicts, then when you fix them, you manually make the commit that records the merge.

Comment: Your answer is incorrect in two places. First: "_merges your current branch with the branch referred to as origin/master_" is incorrect, because `origin/master` is merged **into** current branch. Or maybe this is ambiguity I see in this place, then please clarify. Secondly, `git merge` **does perform commits** in some cases (eg. when not told explicitly to not perform them and when the merge can be performed in fast-forward fashion.

Comment: Yes that is what I meant, I have fixed the wording. Are you saying that a fast-forward is actually the same as a commit? I was under the impression that a fast-forward was more like splicing the new development history on top of your own.

Comment: See this: http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html#_description - especially this line: "_(...) `git merge topic` will replay the changes made on the `topic` branch since it diverged from `master` (...) until its current commit on top of `master`, and **record the result in a new commit** along with the names of the two parent commits and a log message from the user describing the changes_". I believe this is pretty clear. It **does** perform the commit (unless some conflict is detected and you need to resolve it first).

Comment: Ah of course, I see. But the commit is only made if your development has diverged, **not** if it can be done with a fast-forward. The documentation says *In this case, a new commit is not needed to store the combined history; instead, the HEAD (along with the index) is updated to point at the named commit, without creating an extra merge commit.* I will fix up my answer.

Comment: Maybe it is just safer to use `--no-commit`, when you do not want the commit to be created (http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html#_options).